# add custom markers on klokantech/tileserver-gl

Tags: openstreetmap, markers, mbtiles, tileserver-gl

From (https://hub.docker.com/r/klokantech/tileserver-gl) i am able to run `docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/tileserver-gl` successfully and serve the map on localhost. However, I want to add custom markers when I click on the map itself. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please put command in backticks to separate it from text.


Make it clear whether you mean custom marker icons (https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/34002/using-custom-icons-in-your-private-mapnik-rendered-tile-server), a list of markers declared on the server, or adding markers by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The best way is to add markers on a separate page then embed the tileserver-gl as a base map.
- This works fine as added markers can be customized as per requirement.